# iPhone , NSRegularExpression big float

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, parsing, nsregularexpression

I have the following code:

```
-(NSString*)getNumberFromString(NSString*)theString{
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"rhs: \"([0-9]*[.]*[0-9]*)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:theString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [theString length])];
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:0];
    return [theString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
}
```

When I try parsing this string:

```
{lhs: "1 example", rhs: "44.5097254 Indian sample", error: "", icc: true}
```

I get the result `44.5097254`.

But for this string:

```
{lhs: "1 example", rhs: "44.5097254.00.124.2 sample", error: "", icc: true}
```

I get an incorrect result of `44`. I expect to get `44.5097254.00.124.2`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression you are looking for is `rhs: \"(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)`.

```
-(NSString*)getNumberFromString:(NSString*)theString
{
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex =
    [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"rhs: \"(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*)"
                                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines
                                                error:&error];

    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:theString
                                      options:0
                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [theString length])];

    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:0];
    return [theString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
}

...
     NSLog(@"%@", [self getNumberFromString:
                   @"{lhs: \"1 example\", rhs: \"44.5097254.00.124.2 sample\", error: \"\", icc: true}"]);
```

**Output:** `44.5097254.00.124.2`

Comment: @user1466308 I just ran the exact code you posted and logged `44.5097254.00.124.2` to the console using `@"rhs: \"(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*)"` as the expression.

Comment: the problem is i can read this one 44.3 but i can not read 1.100000

Comment: @user1466308 I just ran it through the same code and I got the right value, copy and paste the method in my example into your code and there is no reason that it should not work.

Answer (score 1):

Like I edited in ur previous question adding an * to the end of the regex does the thing:

```
  -(NSString*)getNumberFromString(NSString*)theString{
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"rhs: \"(([0-9]*[.]*[0-9]*)*)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:theString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [theString length])];
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:0];
    return [theString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);

}
```

For the future please try to understand what an answer does. Just copying the code and recognizing that it won't fit your requirements is ok. But first do some research on your own. You could have easily seen that adding the star will make the expression work on values with every length.

Comment: Thats fine,self research is the best thing in programming